# Issue with the menu not being displayed

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a asp.net project with master page which contains menu.ascx
I created a default page, I cant see the menu created in the master page until I press F12 on the IE browser. It seems like the body is covering the header
Any ideas on how i can figureout the issue.
Thanks
Nate

Comment: Can you post your code .. will help ..

Comment: thank you for responding. The issue was, the compatibility mode enabled on the IE browser. Once the compatibility mode was disabled for my box, it started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was, the compatibility mode enabled on the IE browser. Once the compatibility mode was disabled for my box, it started working fine.